# WooCommerce Bookings - Available dates as drop down menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to customize the booking experience. My products are tours spread over the year and scrolling through the calendar to find an available day isn't efficient. What I want is a drop down list that has the next available day for that tour. Is there any plugin or solution for my situation?

Comment: I tried to follow this solution https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-bookings-available-date-drop-down-instead-of-date-picker but I couldn't find date-picker.php

Comment: you should also post why this solution won't work for you and the error get when you try this solution.

Comment: I couldn't find the file 'date-picker.php'

Answer (score 0):

Hi The file is located in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/templates/booking-form

The code in the post described works for the most part but there are some errors

Warning: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /home/betaacademyofflo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/templates/booking-form/date-picker.php on line 54

Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in /home/betaacademyofflo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/templates/booking-form/date-picker.php on line 55

This error appears for every date available.

A tweak that I am trying to make is that currently the select list shows duplicates of each date I need it to just show the date once.

By each date once I mean just the start date my bookings have the same start and end date.

You can see an example here [example list](http://www.academyoffloralart.com/shop/beginners-level-2-floristry/wedding-bridal-floral-design-unit/) I have suppresed the errors for now.
 heres the code so far pretty much the same as the OP version on wordress support.

```
   <?php
   $year = array();
   $month = array();
   $days = array();
   $s;
   $day1;
   $i=0;
   $j=0;

   foreach ($availability_rules as $value) {

    foreach ( $value as  $value2) {

        foreach ( $value2 as  $value3) {

            reset($value3);
            while (list($key, $val) = each($value3)) {

            $year[$i] = $key; //add year to array - $i is the count of how many course

            reset($val);
            while (list($key2, $val2) = each($val)) {
                if($key2 < 10){
                    $month[$i] = '0'.$key2; //add the month value to another array - with leading 0
                }else{

                    $month[$i] = $key2; //add the month value to another array
                }

                $s = "";
                $j = 0;
                reset($val2);
                while (list($key3, $val3) = each($val2)) {

                    if($j==0||$j==1){
                        $s = $s . $key3 .',';
                    }else{
                        $s = $s . $key3;
                    }
                    if($j==0){
                        $day1[$i] = $key3; //add the day value to another array
                    }

                    $j++;

                }
                $days[$i] = $s;
            }

            $i++; //increments each time we loop through a year

            }
        }
     }
   }
   $arrlength = 0;
   $arrlength = count($year); //this is our total amount of courses

   ?>
   <fieldset class="wc-bookings-date-picker <?php echo implode( ' ', $class ); ?>">
   <legend><?php echo $label; ?>: </small></legend>
   <select id="availableDates">
   <option value="">Select Date</option>
   <?php
    if($arrlength==0){
        echo "<option value=''>There are no dates</option>";
    }else{
        $todays_date = date("d-m-Y");   

        $today = strtotime($todays_date);
        for($total_dates = $arrlength -1; $total_dates >= 0; $total_dates--){ //loop through total amount

            $expiration_date =strtotime($day1[$total_dates].'-'.$month[$total_dates].'-'.$year[$total_dates]); 

            $actualdates = $day1[$total_dates]-$month[$total_dates]-$year[$total_dates];
            $displaydates = $day1[$total_dates]/$month[$total_dates]/$year[$total_dates];
            //$input = array( $day1[$total_dates]-$month[$total_dates]-$year[$total_dates]);
            //$result = array_keys($input);

            if ($expiration_date > $today) {




                echo "<option value='$day1[$total_dates]-$month[$total_dates]-$year[$total_dates]'>$day1[$total_dates]/$month[$total_dates]/$year[$total_dates]</option>"; //pull in the index for each date array

            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

What I've tried;

Running an extra foreach on the final result did not work
tried array_unique did not work

Anny guidance here would be most aprreciated.

Comment: I'm still facing the two Warnings. Did you solve this problem?